# Jost solutions of the Sturm Liouville equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, quantum-mechanics

Consider the Sturm Liouville equation:

$$ - \Psi_{xx} + u \Psi = \lambda \Psi $$

Given that the potential $u(x)$ decreases faster than $|x|^{-1- \epsilon}, \epsilon > 0$, when $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ how can I show that there exists a Jost solution $f(x,k)$, which is uniquely fixed by its asymptotic behaviour:

$$ f(x,k) = e^{ikx} + o(1), x \rightarrow \infty $$

$$ f(x,k) \sim a(k)e^{ikx} - \overline{b(k)}e^{-ikx}, x \rightarrow - \infty $$

Comment: If you examine my dissertation, beginning around page 20-21, you will find a proof of the existence of Jost solutions for a system of ODE's. https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/28169/FinalDraft.pdf Perhaps that will help guide you.